Ban entire namespace with BannedApiAnalyzers
I am trying to ban the usage of Newtonsoft.Json package in my codebase, and I am trying to use the BannedApiAnalyzers Nuget package (latest stable version, 3.3.4).
My problem is that while I am able to ban specific classes, I am unable to ban the entire namespace.
Consider the following code for example:
var x = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new object());

When my BannedSymbols.txt file looks like this:
T:Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert;Use System.Text.Json instead
,I get a compilation error, as expected.
But when my BannedSymbols.txt file looks like this: N:Newtonsoft.Json;Use System.Text.Json instead, the build passes.
Banning individual classes is less maintainable and more prone to errors - I want the entire namespace banned.
What am I missing? How can I ban the entire Newtonsoft.Json namespace (and its sub-namespaces, like Newtonsoft.Json.Linq)?

I'm going to guess that the N setting applies to usings, so it's not firing because it's  fully-qualified. The docs suggest the syntax you're using is right, but I would expect what you're doing to work. Maybe file an issue in the repo?

@MartinCostello, interesting thought, but when I switch to a using statement (using Newtonsoft.Json, and then JsonConvert.SerializeObject) the build still passes with the N setting.

I guess it's just a bug then.

I have filed an issue in the repo, will post an update here if there is one in the future.
https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn-analyzers/issues/7340
